# Можно ли сделать, что-то по типу выпадающего списка, в котором можно выбрать картинку, чтобы ее было видно? На Python

Tags: python, tkinter

На Python, пишу приложение. Нужно сделать, что-то по типу профиля, в котором можно выбрать иконку для аватарки, желательно чтобы при выборе картинки было видно, саму картинку. Я делал с помощью выпадающего списка на tkinter, но получилось, только сделать выбор картинки по названию. Пример ниже.[image: Пример]

Вот как я это реализовал.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root=Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 960, height = 720)
canvas.pack()
img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("head.png"))
im1 = Label(root,image=img)
OPTIONS = ['Тигр']
variable = StringVar(root)
variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value

def ok():
    if variable.get()=='Тигр':
        im1.place(x=100,y=100)

w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *OPTIONS)
w.place(x=100,y=150)

button = Button(root, text="OK",command=ok)
button.place(x=100,y=200)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Пример, если что для необходимого результата.

Comment: Ваш код бы в студию)

Comment: От кода, то смысла не очень много. Вот так у меня реализовано через список вызов картинок. А нужно мне, чтобы сами картинки были показанны

Comment: Разве что вручную создавать выпадающее окно такое с прокруткой (т.е., буквально окно без рамки, в котором все будет прокручиваться). Готового контрола такого нет.

Comment: @insolor Хорошо, спасибо за ответ.